# How to define a class (of type db.Model), using a value defined in another class in python to send back data to the front?

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

First of all, I'm using a flask app. 
I collect data from javascript into the back with this code :

```
@app.route('/getFormData', methods=['POST'])
def get_javascript_data():
    params = request.json
    sunElevation = params['sunElevation']
    cloudCoverage = params['cloudCoverage']
    thresholdNDVI = params['thresholdNDVI']
    limitScene = params['limitScene']
    city = params['city']
    coords = params['coords']
    data_search = passData(sunElevation, cloudCoverage, thresholdNDVI, limitScene, city, coords)
    run_script = passData.calcul(data_search)
    return jsonify(data_search.data_dict)
```

Here is my calcul fonction :

```
class passData():
    def __init__(self, sunElevation, cloudCoverage, thresholdNDVI, limitScene, city, coords):
        self.sunElevation = sunElevation
        self.cloudCoverage = cloudCoverage
        self.thresholdNDVI = thresholdNDVI
        self.limitScene = limitScene
        self.city = city
        self.coords = coords
        self.coords.append(self.coords[0])
        self.data_dict = [{'sunElevation':self.sunElevation,
                            'cloudCoverage':self.cloudCoverage,
                            'thresholdNDVI':self.thresholdNDVI,
                            'limitScene':self.limitScene,
                            'city':self.city,
                            'coords':self.coords
                            }]

    def calcul(self):
        main_script(self.sunElevation, self.cloudCoverage, self.thresholdNDVI, self.limitScene, self.city, self.coords)

        return (print("traitement terminé"))
```

In the end ndvi data is stored in the database under the tablename 'ndvi_+city'.
All oh this works well, but after I want to send back this data to the front to visualize the result, Here is the route I use

```
@app.route('/ndviAuto')
def get_ndviAuto():
    query = select([NdviAuto.ogc_fid.label('ogc_fid'), func.ST_AsGeoJSON(func.ST_Transform(NdviAuto.wkb_geometry,4326)).label('wkb_geometry')]).where(NdviAuto.wkb_geometry!=None)
    dataQuery = db.session.execute(query).fetchall()
    data_all = []

    for ndvi in dataQuery:
        ndvi = dict(ndvi)
        data_all.append({
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'properties':{
                            'id':ndvi['ogc_fid'],
                        },
                        'geometry':json.loads(ndvi['wkb_geometry'])
                        })
    return jsonify(data_all)
```

To do so I made a class NdviAuto define like this :

```
class NdviAuto(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'ndvi_' // + city ?
    ogc_fid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    wkb_geometry = db.Column(Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON', srid=32631))
```

My problem is that I don't know how I can construct this class using the value 'city' to get automatically the right table. Right now, the route to send back data works, but I need to change everytime, myself, the table name. 
I use a postgreSQL database.

Comment: What do you mean by "need to change everytime"? Can the *city* change from request to request, or is it fixed during program's lifetime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot modify the `__tablename__` attribute after a [Declarative](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/) class has been created, or in other words you can, but it will have no effect. The [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) object has already been created and assigned to `__table__` attribute and metadata. Declarative [`Base`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base) also keeps a [registry of created classes](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.declarative_base.params.class_registry), so you'll get a warning when redefining the class with a different table, and for a reason: future relationships etc. that use string class names will now point to the redefinition. Usually – but not always – having dynamic table names is a sign of an issue with the DB design.

Since you already have your dynamic tables, you could perhaps employ the light weight [`table()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/selectable.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.table) and [`column()`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.column) constructs instead of full blown Declarative classes or [`Table`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Table) instances. Create a helper function that produces the correct light weight table and use that:

```
def ndvi_auto(city):
    return table(
        'ndvi_{}'.format(city),
        column('ogc_fid', db.Integer),
        column('wkb_geometry', Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON',
                                        srid=32631)))
```

and then in your view:

```
@app.route('/ndviAuto')
def get_ndviAuto():
    ndvi_table = ndvi_auto('some_city')

    query = select([ndvi_table.c.ogc_fid,
                    func.ST_AsGeoJSON(
                        func.ST_Transform(
                            ndvi_table.c.wkb_geometry,
                            4326
                        )
                    ).label('wkb_geometry')]).\
        where(ndvi_table.c.wkb_geometry != None)

    result = db.session.execute(query)

    data = [{'type': 'Feature',
             'properties': { 'id': ndvi.ogc_fid },
             'geometry': json.loads(ndvi.wkb_geometry)}
            for ndvi in result]

    return jsonify(data)
```

Comment: How often do the table names change in practice? Per request, or something else?

Comment: Everytime data are collected from the front, a new table (with the name 'ndvi_' + city is created and that is THAT table I need to access, to show data on the front after. So the table names don't change